# Salesforce - Export a custom contacts view to Excel

Tags: excel, export, salesforce

Is it possible to export a custom contact view to Excel?  I have a button that goes to the ExportContacts.page that is defined like:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" contenttype="application/vnd.ms-excel" recordSetVar="contacts" extensions="ExportContactsExtension" >
  <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="contact">
      <apex:column value="{!contact.LastName}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!contact.FirstName}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingCity}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!contact.Fax}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!contact.MobilePhone}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

The ExportContactsExtension.cls is defined like:

```
public class ExportContactsExtension {

  public ExportContactsExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
    //set the page size so all records will be exported
    controller.setPageSize(controller.getResultSize());
  }

}
```

The question is can I export the specific fields specified in the contacts view?  On the ExportContacts.page, I have to define the fields to export, like last name, first name, etc.  Now if I create a new contacts view and add say the email address, I'll see it on the page, but if I click the export button, it doesn't include the email address.  Can I make that export dynamic to include all of the values from the current view?

Answer (score 1):

Why exactly you need such view in first place? Is there some complex logic in controller for selecting the records?

If the query for them can be written in standard [SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) (like [SELECT FirstName, LastName, MailingCity, Phone, Fax, MobilePhone FROM Contact]), then it might be much more effective for you to export records with [Data Loader](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Apex_Data_Loader) or Excel plugin called "[Excel Connector](http://www.salesforce.com/community/crm-best-practices/administrators/data-management/data-tools/excel-connector.jsp)".

And if you need to be able to both export and (pre)view the data on the Salesforce page - consider creating a report? That's what they are for and there's built-in functionality to export to Excel or CSV.

Comment: The view is the standard Contacts view - it's not a custom controller.  It doesn't include any custom SOQL to retrieve the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your results to Excel by using the contentType attribute on the apex:page component. See the following post:

[Visualforce Export to Excel / IE Bug](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2008/12/29/visualforce-export-to-excel-ie-bug/)

Comment: I updated the ExportContacts.page to include the contenttype - I had that in my page, but took it out to easily see the results without launching Excel each time and didn't paste it into this question.  I can export the specified fields to Excel, but the question still remains as to the best way to export a new field like email address.  Can I do that dynamically on the ExportContacts.page, or do I have to hardcode the fields that will be exported and update them if a new field has to be exported?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what your asking is not possible with apex today.  To do this you'd need a way to query what the page layout was for the record being view and then inspect which fields are visible.